# Creating an instance in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, post

I am getting this error: ***Mongoose Error: Operation `users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms*** when trying to create an instance of User model.
Here is the model/User.js

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    username: {
      type: String,
      min: 3,
      max: 20,
      unique: true,
    },
);

export default mongoose.model("User", UserSchema)
```

And routes/auth.js (where I send request to create User):

```
import express from 'express'
import User from "../models/User.js";
const router = express.Router();
//REGISTER
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    //create new user
    const newUser = new User({
      username: req.body.username,
    });
    //save user and respond
    const user = await newUser.save();
    res.status(200).json("user saved");
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json("error occured")
  }
});
export default router
```

I double checked and found no error at connecting MongoDB or handling get requests. Only problem is with creating User instance on mongoDB.

Comment: Probably not answer to your question, but you have one extra curly brace `{` at the 4.th line in your `User.js`. May be you can delete it and try again.  And also no need for comma `,` here `unique: true` . And you can delete comma after you finish `username` curly brace.

Comment: Thanks, but it has other objects in the codebase, I forgot to delete commas while copying. So this is not the problem.